# Powershell for Browsers Change

Tags: windows, powershell

Today I have written some little code that should change my Default Browser.

Here's my code:

```
  function Set-DefaultBrowser
{
    $browser = (Get-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications").Property | Where-Object -FilterScript{ $ -like "Firefox*"} # Read registered Browsers and Filter Firefox  
    Invoke-Expression "$($exe_path) HKLM $($browser)"
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
 $ : Die Benennung "$" wurde nicht als Name eines Cmdlet, einer Funktion, einer Skriptdatei oder eines ausführbaren Programms erkannt. Überprüfen Sie die Schreibweise des Namens, oder ob der 
Pfad korrekt ist (sofern enthalten), und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang.
In N:\Privat\Dokumente\philips_bs_script.ps1:19 Zeichen:112
+ ... steredApplications").Property | Where-Object -FilterScript{ $ -like " ...
+                                                                 ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ($:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Do you have any solution for this?

Thanks
VallingSki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is hinting that "$" is not the name of a cmdlet known by Powershell. In your `-FilterScript` scriptblock you've typed "$" when you probably meant to type "$_".